# VB6: Obtaining the picture of a label control?

Tags: vb6

Is it possible to obtain the 'picture' of a label control in order to load it into a picture or image control?

Sort of like:

```
  Picture1.Picture = Label1.Picture
```

Except, of course, the label control doesn't have a picture property.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could utilize the GDI32 API to capture what the label looks like. Years ago I found this Microsoft article that outlines how to do it, with source: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/161299

In my case, I utilized it for capturing a form, but it should also work for capturing a label. A picture object is returned, which you could then utilize elsewhere in your app.

Comment: Cool!  Except ... this requires a handle to the object to capture.  Labels are lightweight and don't have a handle.